# systemctl command in centos

Tags: npm, centos7, systemctl

I am trying to execute npm run command as background process in centos by creating it as systemd service . But when I am trying to start, it is giving error Unit not found and when running systemctl enable  it gives error as no such file or directory.

Comment: Is there a systemd service file at all? Systemd can't run a random command without at least a minimal description of how it is supposed to behave.

Answer (score 0):

But you did "systemctl daemon-reload" after installing the unit file? ;)